# Using DjangoFilterConnectionField with custom Connection in graphene_django

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to use something similar to this:

```
class User(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User
        filter_fields = ('email', )
        interfaces = (Node, )
        connection = UserConnection


class UserConnection(Connection):
    extra = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        node = User

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users_connection = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        User,
        where=UserWhereInput()
    )
```

From my understanding, User node needs to be passed UserConnection on it's meta, and UserConnection needs to be passed User on it's meta.

However, it creates a cross reference. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer can be found here:

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/304

```
class UserConnection(Connection):
    extra = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class User(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User
        filter_fields = ('email', )
        interfaces = (Node, )
        connection_class = UserConnection


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users_connection = DjangoFilterConnectionField(User, where=UserWhereInput())
```

Reference: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/pull/313/commits/2a39f5d8eaba3f7772c63b012a974bb9a841fb9f

Comment: I'm still not understanding how you could actually *set* the value of the "extra" field in the connection object. Could you add a definition of resolve_users_connection in your answer that shows how this might be done?